# Javascript Audio - Seek to another position when at a position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a `<audio>` element that is playing through a song. When the song reaches a very specific point, I want it to seek to another specific point seamlessly and keep playing.

Firstly, I'm open and I'm looking for direction as to which is the best  audio API to use to accomplish this, whether that be the [DOM Audio Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp) or the (new) [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Is the best way to set an Event Listener to fire at a certain point in the song (if possible)? Should I play the song and keep a separate timer (but it should be asynchronous)?

Below I've got a basic example. The example should play, but then at a specific point in the audio it should skip seamlessly and keep playing.

Thanks for the help!

```js
$('#player')[0].play();

//$('#player')[0].currentTime = 0.5;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio controls id="player">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use the `Web Audio API` to gain more control over your audio.

Here is some code from MDN:

```
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'yourfilehere.wav', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        myBuffer = buffer;
        source.buffer = myBuffer;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;
        source.loopEnd = //your endOffsetInSeconds
      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});

  }

  request.send();
}
```

How you fetch our data is up to you, but the important part is setting your `source.loop` to true and your `source.loopEnd` to your offset in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm a bit confused as how I could chain this though. For example, if the song started and I wanted it to skip from 1s to 7s, play until 10s then skip to 12s and keep playing how would this be achieved?

I'm dealing with one audio file. From the example you've given me, does that not play the song but when it gets to the `endOffsetInSeconds` it just starts at the beginning again?

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question.  Let me take another look

Comment: honestly i think the easiest thing to do is to create a new audio file from your original with those parts cut out.  You could try [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately splitting the audio files into multiple is not an option. I need to seek through the same audio file